# How to beautify Javascript code in VS2022 Community IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to beautify my javascript code in VS2022 Community IDE, is there any option to automatically creates indent tab according to start and end brackets of the javascript code in VS2022 community IDE:

**Currently:**

```
       <script>

var bootstrapForm = $('.needs-validation'),
jqForm = $('#jquery-val-form'),
picker = $('.picker'),
select = $('.select2');

      </script>
```

I expect to have something like the following:

```
<script>

    var bootstrapForm = $('.needs-validation'),
        jqForm = $('#jquery-val-form'),
        picker = $('.picker'),
        select = $('.select2');

</script>
```

Comment: maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/550115/automatic-format-code-in-visual-studio.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70460978/format-code-and-sort-using-on-save-in-visual-studio-2022 ?